# Caching in AngularJs routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I read the following for routing in AngularJs -

> 'SPA will compose the view, fill in the template, and display the view in the appropriate location within the shell. If the view has already been viewed once, the browser may have cached it and the router will be smart enough not to make the request.'

Is this a default behaviour of `$routeprovider`?
How does this relate to `$templatecacheProvider`.

What would be a way to suppress this behaviour ie forcing `$routeprovider` to not refer to browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has more to do with the $http service, since you're more concerned with template caching:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

> **Caching**
>
> To enable caching, set the request configuration cache
>   property to true (to use default cache) or to a custom cache object
>   (built with $cacheFactory). When the cache is enabled, $http stores
>   the response from the server in the specified cache. The next time the
>   same request is made, the response is served from the cache without
>   sending a request to the server.
>
> Note that even if the response is served from cache, delivery of the
>   data is asynchronous in the same way that real requests are.
>
> If there are multiple GET requests for the same URL that should be
>   cached using the same cache, but the cache is not populated yet, only
>   one request to the server will be made and the remaining requests will
>   be fulfilled using the response from the first request.
>
> You can change the default cache to a new object (built with
>   $cacheFactory) by updating the $http.defaults.cache property. All
>   requests who set their cache property to true will now use this cache
>   object.
>
> If you set the default cache to false then only requests that specify
>   their own custom cache object will be cached.

Basically, when your application is bootstrapped/loaded, you want to set the `$httpProvider.defaults.cache = false`

This will then not cache any of the templates themselves and request the template on every route change.